# Perl - sorting complex data structure

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash, unique

i have an old perl project, a text parser of an eventlog, and received a request to sort the output by event id and to remove duplicate events. So the parser reads a text file and puts each event in an array. Each field on the array contains a hash with multiple key -> value pairs. one key is called sequence and it contains the number of the event. I now want to sort the array based on the sequence value of each array field. Second, I want to remove duplicate identical sequence numbers from the array.

Here some code how I create the array and hashes so you get an idea of the data structure:

```
open (my $mel, "<", $in_filename) or die "\nFile '$in_filename' does not exist or is not readable.\n";

my $i=0;
my $eventcount = 0;

while (<$mel>) {

        # Separate events by "Date/Time" :
        if (/^$/) {
            next;
        }
        if (/^Date\/Time:\s(.*)$/) {
            if ($eventcount >0) {
                $i++;
            }
            $eventcount++; # eventcount initialized with ‘0’
        }

        # Gathering information of the MEL event :
        if (/^Date\/Time:\s(.*)$/) {$MEL[$i]{date} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Sequence number:\s(\d+)$/) {$MEL[$i]{sequence} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Event type:\s([0-9|a-f|A-F]{1,6})$/) {$MEL[$i]{type} = lc $1; next;}
        if (/^Event category:\s(\w+)$/) {$MEL[$i]{category} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Priority:\s(\w+)/) {$MEL[$i]{priority} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Description:\s(.*)$/) {$MEL[$i]{description} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Event specific codes:\s(.*)$/) {$MEL[$i]{code} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Component location:\s(.*)$/) {$MEL[$i]{location} = $1; next;}
        if (/^Logged by:\s.*(.)$/) {$MEL[$i]{logged_by} = $1; next;}
        if (/^4[dD]\s45\s4[cC]\s48\s(\d\d)/) {$MEL[$i]{version} = hex $1;}

}
```

Example of an event in the text file:

```
Date/Time: 2/3/20, 12:18:20 PM
Sequence number: 200 <==============
Event type: 5023
Event category: Command
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Controller return status/function call for requested operation
Event specific codes: b8/1/0
Component type: Controller
Component location: Shelf 99, Bay A
Logged by: Controller in bay A
```

So basically I want to sort an array containing references to hashes based on the value of a key within the hash.

Second I want to remove a field from the array, when the values of a key also exists in a different array field.

I hope someone understands what I need :-)

Is this possible?

Comment: Which field is the "event id"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom sort block to sort the array:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->{sequence} <=> $b->{sequence} } @MEL;
```

But it's much easier to use hash of hashes rather than array of hashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $in_filename = ... ;
open my $mel, '<', $in_filename or die $!;

my %event;

my ($current, $id);
while (<$mel>) {

    next if /^$/;

    if (m{^Date/Time:\s(.*)$}) {
        if (defined $id) {
            $event{$id} = $current;
        }
        $current = { date => $1 };
    } elsif (/^Sequence number:\s(\d+)$/) {
        $id = $1;
    } elsif (/^Event type:\s([0-9|a-f|A-F]{1,6})$/) {
        $current->{type} = lc $1;
    } elsif (/^Event category:\s(\w+)$/) {
        $current->{category} = $1;
    } elsif (/^Priority:\s(\w+)/) {
        $current->{priority} = $1;
    } elsif (/^Description:\s(.*)$/) {
        $current->{description} = $1;
    } elsif (/^Event specific codes:\s(.*)$/) {
        $current->{code} = $1;
    } elsif (/^Component location:\s(.*)$/) {
        $current->{location} = $1;
    } elsif (/^Logged by:\s.*(.)$/) {
        $current->{logged_by} = $1;
    } elsif (/^4[dD]\s45\s4[cC]\s48\s(\d\d)/) {
        $current->{version} = hex $1;
    }
}

for my $e (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %event) {
    say 'Sequence number:', $e;
    for my $k (sort keys %{ $event{$e} }) {
        say "$k: $event{$e}{$k}";
    }
}
```

It can be further simplified by building one large regex to match most of the details:

```
my $regex = qr/
               Event\ type:\s(?<type>[0-9|a-f|A-F]{1,6})$
              |Event\ category:\s(?<category>\w+)$
              |Priority:\s(?<priority>\w+)
              |Description:\s(?<description>.*)$
              |Event\ specific\ codes:\s(?<code>.*)$
              |Component\ location:\s(?<location>.*)$
              |Logged\ by:\s.*(?<logged>.)$
              |4[dD]\s45\s4[cC]\s48\s(?<version>\d\d)
/x;

while (<$mel>) {
    next if /^$/;

    if (m{^Date/Time:\s(.*)$}) {
        if (defined $id) {
            $current->{type} = lc $current->{type}
                if exists $current->{type};
            $current->{version} = hex $current->{version}
                if exists $current->{version};
            $event{$id} = $current;
        }
        $current = { date => $1 };
    } elsif (/^Sequence number:\s(\d+)$/) {
        $id = $1;
    } elsif (/^$regex/) {
        $current->{ (keys %+)[0] } = (values %+)[0];
    } else {
        warn "Skipping: $_";
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice regexp lesson. But I can't see how this would register the last record in `%event` when there isn't any next `Date/Time` to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much. The first answer for the array works. I see that using a hash is more nice, but I have about 1000 lines of code that is looping through the values a few times. Changing the array to a hash would need me to rewrite all the code.

Comment: Any idea how I can remove duplicates of the array based on sequence number?

Comment: Ah, found it:
my %seen;
@MEL = grep { ! $seen{$_->{sequence}}++ } @MEL;

Comment: @SiegfriedHepp: If you use the second solution, it handles the unique for you.

Comment: @KjetilS. It registers a new record immediately when encountering its Date/Time.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem is not complete. It is not clear if the records are homogeneous (all same type).

Well if assumption above is correct then task is quite simple.

Split the file into records, then fill hash with **event number** as key and record as value skipping duplicates.

Then sort on key hash and output the record.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %events;
my %seen;
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s!\n(Date/Time)!\n\n$1!g;

my @data = split '\n\n', $data;

for my $record (@data) {
    my $event = get_event_n( $record );

    next if $seen{$event};

    $seen{$event}   = 1;
    $events{$event} = $record;
}

say '----- Sorted Events -----';

for my $event (sort keys %events) {
    say $events{$event};
    say '-' x 45;                 # record separator as visual indicator
}

sub get_event_n {
    my $record = shift;
    my $sequence;

    $record =~ /Sequence number:\s+(\d+)/;
    $sequence = $1;

    return $sequence;
}

__DATA__
Date/Time: 2/3/20, 12:19:20 PM
Sequence number: 230
Event type: 5023
Event category: Command
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Controller return status/function call for requested operation
Event specific codes: b8/1/0
Component type: Controller
Component location: Shelf 99, Bay A
Logged by: Controller in bay A
Date/Time: 2/3/20, 12:18:20 PM
Sequence number: 200
Event type: 5023
Event category: Command
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Controller return status/function call for requested operation
Event specific codes: b8/1/0
Component type: Controller
Component location: Shelf 99, Bay A
Logged by: Controller in bay A
Date/Time: 2/3/20, 12:18:25 PM
Sequence number: 205
Event type: 5023
Event category: Command
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Controller return status/function call for requested operation
Event specific codes: b8/1/0
Component type: Controller
Component location: Shelf 99, Bay B
Logged by: Controller in bay B
Date/Time: 2/3/20, 12:18:28 PM
Sequence number: 209
Event type: 5023
Event category: Command
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Controller return status/function call for requested operation
Event specific codes: b8/1/0
Component type: Controller
Component location: Shelf 92, Bay B
Logged by: Controller in bay B
Date/Time: 2/3/20, 12:18:25 PM
Sequence number: 205
Event type: 5023
Event category: Command
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Controller return status/function call for requested operation
Event specific codes: b8/1/0
Component type: Controller
Component location: Shelf 99, Bay B
Logged by: Controller in bay B
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on @choroba's nice regexp, but I think this one is simpler:

```
my $key = 'sequence';  #or other fields
my $keep = 'first';    #or 'last' record with identical $key

my $regex = qr{
   Date/Time:              \s* (?<date>.*)
  |Sequence\ number:       \s* (?<sequence>\d+)
  |Event\ type:            \s* (?<type>[0-9|a-f|A-F]{1,6})
  |Event\ category:        \s* (?<category>\w+)
  |Priority:               \s* (?<priority>\w+)
  |Description:            \s* (?<description>.*)
  |Event\ specific\ codes: \s* (?<code>.*)
  |Component\ location:    \s* (?<location>.*)
  |Logged\ by:             \s* (?<logged_by>.*)
  |4[dD]\s45\s4[cC]\s48\s(?<version>\d\d)
}x;

my @event=();
while (<>) {
  m{^Date/Time:} and push @event, {};
  m{^$regex}     and @{$event[-1]}{keys %+} = values %+;
}

#special treatment for type and version: hex and lc
exists $$_{type}    and $$_{type}    = hex $$_{type}    for @event;
exists $$_{version} and $$_{version} = lc  $$_{version} for @event;

#mark for deletion
my %exists; $exists{$$_{$key}}++ and $$_{delete}=1
   for $keep eq 'first' ? @event
     : $keep eq 'last'  ? reverse(@event)
     : die "keep must be first or last";

#delete those marked
@event = grep !$$_{delete}, @event;

#sort by $key
@event = sort { $$a{$key} <=> $$b{$key} } @event;
```

I guessed that type should be `hex`ed and version should be `lc`ed, not the other way around like in the question.

Run like:

```
perl script.pl input_file
```